# Docker keeps autostarting

Tags: systemd, docker

Having disabled the Docker daemon, it keeps starting automatically after boot. This is a problem because it should only be started after the encryption is mounted.

The docker service should be disabled (thus not autostarting) and manually started as soon as LUKS /srv is mounted.

I tried disabling it with:

```
systemctl disable docker
update-rc0 docker disable
update-rc0 -f docker remove
echo manual >> /etc/init/docker.override
```

What could be the issue?

```
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-07-02 10:39:13 CEST; 3h 35min ago
Docs: https://docs.docker.com
Main PID: 6736 (dockerd)
Tasks: 23
Memory: 51.4M
CPU: 1min 7.659s
CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
`-6736 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

Comment: whats the output of systemctl status docker ?

Comment: @JeanMi Added to OP

Comment: what OSS are you using ? did you try `sudo update-rc.d docker disable` and `sudo bash -c 'echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/docker.override'` ?

Comment: Hi @JeanMi. As mentioned in the OP, both have been executed already

Comment: I think your command appends to docker.override whereas mine replace the content, if i'm right.

Comment: That's right, but the file already contains manual. It's annoying that nothing fixes it

Comment: Sorry I'm running out of ideas, what distribution are you running?

Comment: Running Debian Buster now, upgraded over time from version 8 I think.